# jQuery - function with custom callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I'm trying to execute a specific function once some processes finished executing.

My specific example refers to a number of animate() methods after which I want to call another function, however this function should only be called once the animate() methods finished processing:

```
var testObject = {
    methodOne : function(callbackMethod) {
        $('#item').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '20px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
        $('#item2').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '30px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
        $('#item3').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '40px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
        testObject.callbackMethod();
    },
    run : function() {
        alert('done');
    }
};

$(function() {

      testObject.methodOne(run);

});
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provided you are using jQuery >= 1.5, then you should use the `Deferred`-functionality:

```
var testObject = {
    methodOne : function($elements, callbackMethod) {
        $elements.each(function (i) {
           $(this).animate({ 'paddingLeft' : (10 + (10*i)) + 'px'}, { duration: 200 * i, queue: false });
        });
        $elements.promise().done(callbackMethod);
    },
    run : function() {
       $('.wrapper').append('<span>Finished!</span>');
    }
};

$(function() {
  testObject.methodOne($('#item, #item2, #item3'), testObject.run);
});
```

jsFiddle for this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z4zu/

A cleaner/refactored version could look like this:

```
var testObject = {
    methodOne : function($elements, callbackMethod) {
        $elements.each(function (i) {
           $(this).animate({ 'paddingLeft' : (10 + (10*i)) + 'px'}, { duration: 200 * i, queue: false });
        });
        $elements.promise().done(callbackMethod);
    },
    run : function() {
       $('.wrapper').append('<span>Finished!</span>');
    }
};

$(function() {
  testObject.methodOne($('#item, #item2, #item3'), testObject.run);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Z4zu/1/

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about the Promise objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom event to be fired when an animation stops, for example:

```
$("body").bind("animationsComplete", function() {
  testObject.completed++;
  if (testObject.completed == testObject.needToComplete) {
    testObject.run();
  }
});
```

In each of your functions you should trigger that event:

```
var testObject = {
    needToComplete : 3,
    completed : 0,
    methodOne : function(callbackMethod) {
        $('#item').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '20px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            trigger("animationsComplete");
        }});
        $('#item2').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '30px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            trigger("animationsComplete");
        }});
        $('#item3').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '40px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            trigger("animationsComplete");
        }});
    },
    run : function() {
        alert('done');
    }
};
```

EDIT: I understand that I lost some functionality of your original code (defining which function to be called as callback) but I think you'll know basically what I had in mind.

Comment: +1 because using custom events is a good alternative to using `Deferred`-functionality

Answer (score 1):

You can count the animate function calls and decrement that number in each animation callback. In the callbacks, if all the other animations have finished you call the "master" callback :

```
var testObject = {
    methodOne : function(callbackMethod) {
        var animationsCount = 3;
        $('#item').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '20px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            if(--animationsCount == 0)
                testObject[callbackMethod]();
        }});
        $('#item2').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '30px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            if(--animationsCount == 0)
                testObject[callbackMethod]();
        }});
        $('#item3').animate({ 'paddingLeft' : '40px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false ,complete : function(){
            if(--animationsCount == 0)
                testObject[callbackMethod]();
        }});
    },
    run : function() {
        alert('done');
    }
};

$(function() {

      testObject.methodOne('run');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have all of the success callbacks from each animate function increase a counter and call the same function (your `callbackMethod`).

In `callbackMethod`, you check to see if the counter has hit 3 and then only perform your desired code if it has.

Or work the opposite way from 3 down to 0, or 3 separate booleans, you've got many options to you at that point.